# Python - Sort boxes based on score and position

Tags: python

I have been working on the following problem: I have an array of an unknown number of rectangles each with a corresponding "score" :

`[{"topleft": {"x": 20, "y": 60},
   "bottomright": {"x": 540,"y": 600},
   "score": 50},
  etc.]`

I am wanting to sequentially remove these rectangles until I arrive at the last rectangle. The big stipulation, however, is that on each iteration I am wanting to remove one of the *outermost* rectangles with the lowest score. By *outermost* I mean if a bounding box were drawn around all the remaining rectangles, the outermost ones would be the ones that touch that bounding box.

Here's an example:

[image]

For the purposes of this illustration the boxes with the highest scores are red, lowest scores are light blue (the smallest rectangle there) and the dark blue ones have medium scores.

First I would remove the largest red square that contains all of them as it is the only box that shares a side with the "bounding box".

Then three boxes would share a side with the bounding box, the small red one and the two dark blue ones. I would remove one of the dark blue ones (whichever had the smallest score)

This would continue until I was left with only the small red box (in this case). Hopefully that makes sense.

Until now I have basically designed an algorithm that loops through all remaining boxes and finds the box  with the smallest score that also shares a side with the bounding box - then I remove that box and repeat. This works just fine - but seems fairly inefficient to me.

I'm wondering if anyone has any clever ideas as to how to sort the boxes in the order they need to be removed and then I'd just iterate through the sorted array and remove the boxes sequentially. Or maybe it wouldn't even be any more efficient to do it that way?

Comment: How many boxes are there? Unless there are thousands, I highly doubt that optimizing this is worth any time or energy.

Comment: Probably at a maximum a few hundred - but usually less than a hundred. In addition to optimizing I just thought the code would be a little cleaner if there was some short sorting algorithm that could handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build four lists each orders the boxes such that each has the boxes in outer to inner order from top to bottom, bottom to top, from left to right, from right to left. Then you could pick what box to remove with:

```
b = min([tb[0], bt[0], lr[0], rl[0]], key=lambda b: b["score"])
tb.remove(b)
bt.remove(b)
lr.remove(b)
rl.remove(b)
```

Building each of these lists requires a sort:

```
tb = sorted(boxes, key=lambda b: b["topleft"]["y"])
lr = sorted(boxes, key=lambda b: b["topleft"]["x"])
bt = sorted(boxes, key=lambda b: b["bottomright"]["y"], reverse=True)
rl = sorted(boxes, key=lambda b: b["bottomright"]["x"], reverse=True)
```

Each of these orders the boxes in outer to inner order along one of the four sides of the boxes.

Comment: Thanks very much - that certainly looks like a cleaner solution than what I previously had, any ideas if it would be more efficient though? Obviously without both pieces of code you can't benchmark it - but doing 4 sorts seems fairly taxing..no?

Comment: With something like this, I'd 100% go for the cleaner solution than the fastest solution. If your users can't perceive any slowdown, then it's definitely worth having easily maintainable code.

Comment: Actually the sorts are cheap, it is the removes that are expensive.